# iOS Development on iPad or Web App for iPhone

Tags: ios

I need to begin evelopment for iOS, can I use iPad Pro for that? Does it support xcode and Swift? 
If not, how can I create a web app that runs on iOS and is developed on a PC?

The budget is rather tight and Mac is ecxpensive. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you have the financial resources for an iPad Pro, you can definitely afford a MacMini, since the base product is cheaper than an iPad Pro. However, this question is completely off-topic here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot develop an iOS app on an iPad. You need a Mac.

Comment: I suppose it's possible to do it by pretending somehow that your PC is a Mac, but I wouldn't know anything about that.

Comment: The key word is "touts". Advertising and reality aren't the same. Your counterexample is an excellent one.